# Qt setWindowTitle on Mac does not change icon in dock

Tags: c++, macos, qt

The problem appears when I try to build a single binary on Mac. It is working fine when building my application as a bundle. Then it just takes the icon defined in the info.plist. 
Another thing is that I want to avoid displaying my application icon in the dock at all? Any way to do that?

I need a solution for one of the issues, either show a custom icon in dock, or don't show any icon.

Have somebody had the same issue and maybe found a workaround or solution?